# MATLAB: How to concatenate two numeric matrices such that the corresponding numbers in each matrix are now concatenated

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

For example lets take matrices:

```
A= 1 0 0
   0 1 0
   1 1 0

B= 1 1 0
   0 0 1
   1 0 0
```

The required result is

```
AB=11 01 00
   00 10 01
   11 10 00
```

Comment: Can you add code? What do you have/ have tried and does not work?

Comment: What format exactly is `AB`? A cell array of strings?

Comment: Is the question restricted to logicals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
reshape(mat2cell(dec2bin(A+B), ones(numel(A),1)), size(A))
```

Or a more compact suggestion from Rody:

```
reshape(num2cell(dec2bin(A+B), 2), size(A))
```

Comment: +1, but I'd change the inner part to `num2cell(dec2bin(A+B), 2)`

Comment: also: your solution consumes 576 bytes, whereas an all-logical solution consumes 18 bytes...In fact, a cell-based solution always consumes 32 times more memory than a pure logical one. That might not be a bad thing (the question is not very specific), but it might matter to someone :)

Comment: How do you extend this to three or more matrices?
Once the elements are in the cell array I'm unable to operate on them as previously done

Comment: @user3769974 `dec2bin(A+B+C+D...)`

Answer (score 2):

3 ways pop in mind; it depends a bit on what you want *exactly*.

```
% Example data (make them logical to save space)
A= [1 0 0
    0 1 0
    1 1 0] == 1;

B= [1 1 0
    0 0 1
    1 0 0] == 1;

%# Method 1
cols = size(A,2) + size(B,2);
C1(:, 1:2:cols) = A;
C1(:, 2:2:cols) = B


%# Method 2
C2 = cellfun(@horzcat, num2cell(A),num2cell(B), 'UniformOutput',false)
C2{:,1}

%# Method 3 (same as 2, really, but simpler)
C3 = strcat(num2cell(A), num2cell(B))
C3{:,1}
```

Comment: Thanks. The second method helped. Though I needed the elements stored in the cell array as a string. Should have mentioned that. Anyways Dan's answer covers that.